# Remove Rows occurring after a String R Data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I want to remove all rows after a certain string occurrence in a data frame column. I want to only return the 3 rows that appear above "total" appearing in column A. The 2 rows appearing below "total" would be excluded.

```
A            B       
Bob Smith    01005
Carl Jones   01008
Syndey Lewis 01185
total
Adam Price   01555
Megan Watson 02548
```

Comment: @NadPat The linked question is about remoiving rows containing specific strings. OP wants to remove every row below (and including) a specific string which isn't exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can subset with `row_number`and `which`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(row_number() < which(A=='total'))

             A     B
1    Bob Smith 01005
2   Carl Jones 01008
3 Syndey Lewis 01185
```

Comment: Good answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(cumsum(A == "total") == 0)
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  A            B    
  <chr>        <chr>
1 Bob Smith    01005
2 Carl Jones   01008
3 Syndey Lewis 01185
```

### Data

```r
structure(list(A = c("Bob Smith", "Carl Jones", "Syndey Lewis", 
"total", "Adam Price", "Megan Watson"), B = c("01005", "01008", 
"01185", NA, "01555", "02548")), problems = structure(list(row = 4L, 
    col = NA_character_, expected = "2 columns", actual = "1 columns", 
    file = "literal data"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(A = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), B = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```r
A <- c('Bob Smith','Carl Jones','Syndey Lewis','total','Adam Price','Megan Watson')

B <- c('01005','01008','01185','','01555','02548')

df <- data.frame(A, B) 

val =  which(df$A=="total")  #get index of total

C = df[1:val-1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little clunky but this should solve what you're wanting it to do:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(A = c("Bob Smith", "Carl Jones", "Sydney Lewis", "total", "Adam Price", "Megan Watson"),
                 B = c("01005", "01008", "01185", NA, "01555", "02548"))

index <- df[df$A=="total",] %>% rownames()
df %>% slice(1:index)
```

Comment: I don't think this works. There are no rownames.

Comment: You could rearrange your code slightly: `df %>% slice_head(n = which(.$A == "total") - 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinGal. It works on dataframes which are mostly the default data type. Now that I added the code specifying that this works on dataframes, this code works.